# Why was my question closed as "Not reproducible or caused by typo"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

Why was my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78037768/docker-compose-env-property-not-taken-into-account) closed as "not reproducible or caused by a typo"?

- One user *did* suggest in the comments it was a wrong property format, but then they took their words back since the format of `property: value` *is* supported by `docker-compose`, as [supported](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#environment) by the documentation
- To reproduce, one has to paste a `docker-compose` into a Boot project with the Eureka starter, all of which was specified

What exactly did I do wrong?

Comment: It probably is a typo, but it shouldn't be closed until that is confirmed IMO. Very premature.

Comment: @Gimby can you undo it?

Comment: @Gimby Agree, just voted to reopen (and it was just reopened).

Comment: @Yodevir well no, but we have the power to cast reopen votes so multiple people do have the power to reverse the decision. I wouldn't personally in this case since it is my belief that it is a typo, the act of reopening it would only mean it should be closed again at some point.

Comment: @Gimby but didn't I reference the documentation that explicitly described that format?

Comment: @Yodevir I generally take more notice of the situation which is right on front of your eyes, documentation is a guideline only. The clearly visible situation is that you think you are setting an environmental variable which should then be interpreted by the Spring Boot yaml parser, but that is not happening. So... the variable is not set. The easiest answer for that is: wrong configuration. Typo.  You can confirm that by SSHing to a running docker container and seeing if the environmental variable actually exists. I'm pretty sure it does not.

Comment: @Gimby it exists, please see my last edit

Comment: Is this even a programming question? It looks like a server environment configuration question.

Comment: @TylerH to me, it is certainly a programming question. Maybe, it's some Boot thing, see the last edit

Comment: @TylerH I, too, thought it were not (and voted to close as such, not as a typo); on re-reading the guidelines of [tag:docker] ("*if your question is about something happening inside the container, it's probably on-topic here*") I was not so sure, so I erred to the side of ambiguity, and voted to reopen.